# Open .prn file that includes image with right Encoding using c#

Tags: c#, image, encoding, character-encoding, honeywell

I need to open a .prn file and replace some strings.

In the .prn file I included an image, that has a string like this:
[image]

When I open the .prn file, C# is not able to read the string as it is.

Probably, it misses some encoding, but not sure which one.

I tried different encodings, but without success.

Here is the code that opens the file in read mode:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(root + @"testImage.prn");
```

c# reads that string in this way

[image]

and i'm not able to print the file with the image included.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's not a text file, don't read it as such.

Comment: What's a "prn file"? What is the actual format of that file? Do you have specs?

Answer (score 2):

Most PRN files contain ISO encoding. So, try using ISO encoding and read the file using System.IO.StreamReader with explicitly specifying the desired encoding.

The following example worked perfectly in my case:

```
System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
string text;
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path, encoding))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it worked this way for me: Using Stream and charset ISO-8859-1.

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```